# AppImage - AppRun gives segmentation fault

Tags: qt, qml, strace, appimage

I have a Qt-Qml application that i've built and packed on Ubuntu 20.04.2 using `appimage-builder`. I tried to deploy it to a Debian 10.8.0 virtual machine. When I try and run the `.AppImage` it is waiting for a couple seconds and then stopping with no output. If i run from extracted AppRun, it will give a segmentation fault. I've run AppRun with strace and i saw many dependency issues. I shared the output of `strace ./AppRun 2>&1 | grep openat | grep \\.so` below maybe it helps.

I don't know what to do next. I made sure each library which strace outputted is in the AppDir under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. I cannot share the output here because of the character limit. Here's a [link](https://codeshare.io/5edm19) to it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if helps anything but there is a double slash at .../squashfs-root//usr/...

Comment: Hi @Jax297 i'm aware of double slashes too, that is generated by strace app. I have no idea why.

Comment: Please open an issue in the appimage-builder repo. Make sure to include a binary for inspection and if possible the source code and recipe being used.

https://github.com/AppImageCrafters/appimage-builder/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware Ubuntu 20 is based on Debian 11. So you compiled with newer kernel and libraries than what you have at runtime. This almost certainly leads to problems.

You may want to compile on Ubuntu 18 (which is based on Debian 10), then run on Ubuntu 20. This more likely contains compatible changes than the way you tried.

See also https://askubuntu.com/a/445496/1182429